# Spring versions compatibility

Tags: spring, sftp, spring-batch, spring-integration

For a project I want to use spring batch and spring integration sftp component as in [Send data secure with sftp and spring batch](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/09/send-data-secure-with-sftp-and-spring-batch/).

I tried the following versions :

Spring-context 4.0.4.RELEASE (same used for other spring components)

Spring batch 2.1.9.RELEASE

Spring Integration *3.0.1.RELEASE*

And I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties
at org.springframework.integration.config.xml.AbstractIntegrationNamespaceHandler.registerImplicitChannelCreator(AbstractIntegrationNamespaceHandler.java:153)
at org.springframework.integration.config.xml.AbstractIntegrationNamespaceHandler.parse(AbstractIntegrationNamespaceHandler.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1297)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
... 41 more
```

Can any one help me trough this configuration since I'm newbie with the use of spring.

Comment: While I don't think it's a cause of your issue, I'd recommend updating your batch version as well to at least 2.2.6.RELEASE if you're going to be updating the Spring core and integration versions.

Comment: It implies you don't have the `4.0.1.RELEASE` version of `spring-integration-core` on your classpath.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties, this means it is missing a spring integration class org.springframework.integration.*, now... who needs this class? org.springframework.integration.config.xml.*, so basically, it is spring integration class that needs another spring integration class but cannot find it. @GaryRussell is correct, check and re-check your classpath for the correct jars.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the description I used 3.0.1.RELEASE version of spring integration and not 4.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: It worked with spring batch version 2.2.6.RELEASE thank you @MichaelMinella